# How do I fix multipoint Bluetooth on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: sound, 20.04, bluetooth, dell

I have the Jabra Elite 65t multipoint-capable Bluetooth earphones. On Ubuntu 20.04, I can connect to both my Pixel 3a XL running Android 11 and my XPS 13 9380 laptop. When my Pixel 3a XL receives any audio, it steals audio focus from the XPS 13. Audio focus never returns to the XPS, despite remaining connected. Web video will load but not play.

The XPS has a Killer 1435 module with support for Bluetooth 4.2.

How do I enable true multipoint Bluetooth connectivity?